# Reading from AWS S3 with Apache Beam Go SDK

Tags: go, amazon-s3, apache-beam

We are using the Go SDK for building pipelines. I think Apache Beam already supports AWS S3 for Python and Java. Is there a plan to add it for the Go SDK?

Comment: What version of Beam Go SDK are you using?

Comment: Hi Eduardo, thanks for looking at this question and improvement! We are currently using v2.35.0. The reason why I asked was that I did not find any instruction of reading inputs from S3 with the Go sdk, and there seemed to be no related package yet used in https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/filesystem Or is it actually supported in any version?

Comment: No problem Tao, i found this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/) regarding using AWS S3 with go, does it helps you?

Comment: Thanks Eduardo! The link you shared is about the S3 apis, but what I want to ask is when it can be integrated into the apache Beam io package. Analogy to the GCS apis, they are integrated in the path [io/filesystem/gcs](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/filesystem/gcs)

Answer (score 0):

according to this page https://github.com/apache/beam/releases

**S3 implementation of the Beam filesystem (Go) (#23991).**

s3 system can be use in beam package and according to https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/filesystem/filesystem.go

```
var wellKnownSchemeImportPaths = map[string]string{
    "memfs":   "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/io/filesystem/memfs",
    "default": "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/io/filesystem/local",
    "gs":      "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/io/filesystem/gcs",
    "s3":      "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/v2/go/pkg/beam/io/filesystem/s3",
}
```

s3 schema is recognized
so maybe just use

```
textio.Read(s, "s3://some file path...")
```

But maybe... you meet error set aws credentials first
set environment variables are probably the easiest way.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html

I'm sorry I can't help more because I don't have a test environment.